# Is there a way to preserve an order of shuffled ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

i am currently in progress of testing my dataset with tensorflow,
however when i want to create a shuffled data for testing, there is a problem.
when i want to create confusion matrix i need to pass (y_true, y_pred)

In my case y_true is my test_set :

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('path',
                                        target_size = (280, 280),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical',
                                        subset="validation",
                                        shuffle=True
                                        )
```

and i will feed test_set to model.predict() and will result in y_pred.

In this case when i want to create an array contanining labels of the **shuffled data**.
However if i use test_set.labels it will return the labels of the **ordered data** which are not on **shuffled state order**.
is there a way to output the labels of the shuffled data labels?

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle can be controlled by setting shuffle=False.

> shuffle:  Whether to shuffle the data (default: True) If set to False,
> sorts the data in alphanumeric order.

Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) for more details.